# How do you get RequireSSL in NodeJS on an Azure Website?

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service, requiressl

So a little background first: A NodeJS server running in an Azure Website will automatically have all HTTPS requests [directed to the http endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19107611/3695975). This allows the following code to work for both HTTP and HTTPS

```
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');

var app = express();
// *snip*
http.createServer(app).listen(process.env.PORT);
// can go to http://*.azurewebsites.net or https://*.azurewebsites.net without issue
```

From here I decided to create a "RequireSSL" middleware

```
/* snip */
if (req.protocol === 'http') {
    var origFullUrl: string = 'http://' + req.get('host') + req.originalUrl;
    var u: url.Url = url.parse(origFullUrl, true);
    u.host = null; // nead to clear so 'port' is used
    u.protocol = 'https';
    u.port = '443';

    res.redirect(url.format(u));
}
/* snip */
```

Here's where the background comes into play. Because Azure redirects all HTTPS to the HTTP protocol the req.protocol *always* equals 'http' creating a redirect loop.

Anyone know of a way to get this to work in an Azure Website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can detect this using  x-arr-ssl header.. Please go through this : https://coderead.wordpress.com/2014/09/05/redirecting-to-https-in-node-js-on-azure-websites/